# Google ARCore: TrackableHit on detected plane - how to get surface normal?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

In my application I'm using Google ARCore to raycast into the recognized world. In the case that the ray is hitting a detected plane I would like to know the surface normal of the hit.

How could one achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure but if i remember correctly (example for clicking)

```
TrackableHit hit;
TrackableHitFlags raycastFilter = TrackableHitFlags.PlaneWithinPolygon | TrackableHitFlags.FeaturePointWithSurfaceNormal;

if (Frame.Raycast(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, raycastFilter, out hit))
{
    Vector3 normal = hit.Pose.up;
}
```